# How to handle redundancy in mysql After Insert Trigger

Tags: mysql

I have an after insert trigger, when the trigger is executed it inserts multiple rows in another table. I want only single entry to be inserted.

Below is the query :

```
CREATE TRIGGER Afterinsert_userbadge AFTER INSERT ON `user_match_result`FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
DECLARE goalCount INT(10);  
DECLARE badgeId BIGINT(20);  
declare userId bigint(20) default 0 ;  

SELECT sum(goal) INTO goalCount FROM user_match_result WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;  

IF  goalCount > = 1 THEN  

    SELECT badge_id INTO badgeId FROM badge_master WHERE name  = 'FIRST OF MANY';  
    SELECT user_id into userId FROM user_badges 
    WHERE badges_id = badgeId and user_id = NEW.user_id 
    AND match_id = NEW.match_id;  

    IF (userId <> 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO user_badges(badges_id,user_id,match_id,created_date)   
        SELECT badgeId, NEW.user_id,NEW.match_id,NEW.created_date 
        FROM user_match_result;   
    END IF;  

END IF;  

END
```

Here 34 rows get inserted on user_badges table if a single entry is done on user_match_result table.

Comment: well you have `FROM user_match_result;` with no limiting `where` or whatever. So it is picking up all the rows in that table.

Comment: @@ Drew :  Thank you so much... added limit 1 in the insert query and it worked.